# Mocking json response in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, unit-testing, rspec

I am getting a `json response` from my API. Is there a way we can mock this `json` response to compare it with API.

```
it "should find all accounts" do 
  let(:myjson) {
            "@type": "userResource",
            "createdAt": "2014-08-14T07:32:52",
            "createdBy": 2,
            "updatedAt": "2014-08-14T07:32:52",
            "updatedBy": 2,
            "email": "12@12.com",
            "name": "test",
            "password": "",
            "confirmpassword": "",
            "id": 2856,
            "accountid": 0,
            "resetpw": false,                
   }
  expect(response.body).to eq(myjson);
emd
```

Is there a way we can mock json, so that i don't need to hard-code it in my spec.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have some kind of setup to create accounts in the database before you make the API call, so you can serialize those accounts to JSON in your tests and use that compare with the API response.

Something like this:

```
accounts = [ Account.create(...), Account.create(...) ]
expected_response = accounts.as_json
expect(response.body).to eq(expected_response)
```